# Selecting all rows from random levels of a df

Tags: r

From other questions and answers is possible to understand how to randomly sample "n" rows from a df, or "n" rows that originate from a specific level of a factor within a df. However I did not find how to select all the rows from random "n" levels from a DF.

Here is a working df.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(80), nrow=40))
df$color <-  rep(c("blue", "red", "yellow", "pink","purple","brown","green","olive"), each=5)
df$color <-as.factor(df$color)
```

What I want to do is to obtain a different df with a random sample with all the 5 rows of 4 colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first `filter` the dataset based on the 'color' we wanted and `slice` the `sample`d `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(color %in% sample(unique(color), 4)) %>%
    slice(sample(row_number()))
```

---

NOTE: It is not clear whether the 'color' should be `sample`d as well.  So, we included that it in the `filter` step

We can create a function based on the above

```
fSample <- function(dat, colr, n) {
        colr <- enquo(colr)
        dat %>%
             filter(UQ(colr) %in% sample(unique(UQ(colr)), n)) %>%
             slice(sample(row_number()))
}

fSample(df, color, 4)
```

Comment: OK, Thanks! I see how it works. However I have a problem, I need to get all the rows from the level that Im sampling... In my real dataset I cant specify how many rows like you do (sample_n(1)), since each level has different number of rows and I need all of them. If I remove this line (sample_n(1)) the script does not work any more. Ok, got it, just deleted everything included the last %>%. Thanks

Comment: @Cisco  I changed it.  Now u will get all the rows from the filtered color

Comment: Im having a weird error with dplyr... My R didnt found enquo() so I reinstall dplyer and got this:
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘DBI’ 0.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr

Comment: @Cisco Could you update your R and then install dplyr.  I am using R 3.4.1

Comment: Yeah, my version is R version 3.2.1... Im going to update it thanks

Comment: Done and solve! Thanks, the function works very nicely! Thanks a lot